# How to render greek characters in japanese (luatexja) document

Tags: luatex, greek, japanese, luatexja

I have a document in Japanese (with the luatexja package), but I need to render a sentence in Greek halfway down (actually a lot of languages, but Greek is currently the only one giving issues).

This mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\begin{document}
Japanese: 日本語のサンプルテキスト 

Greek: Παράδειγμα κειμένου στα ελληνικά
\end{document}
```

Renders like this:
[image]

As you can see the spacing is off and some characters don't render at all.

I've tried to surround the greek text like so:
`{\fontfamily{FreeSans}\selectfont Παράδειγμα κειμένου στα ελληνικά}`
but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font used for greek by setting a parameter (found in the documentation) and using `\setmainfont` to select a suitable font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2,-3}}
\setmainfont{FreeSans} 
\begin{document}
Japanese: 日本語のサンプルテキスト 

Greek: Παράδειγμα κειμένου στα ελληνικά


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. This works with full luatexja as well. Where did you find that `\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2,-3}}` in the docs?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I edited my comment at the same time you added your reply

Comment: on page 5: Greek and Cyrillic letters, and ISO 8859-1 symbols